# Find duplicate records with different spellings in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, drupal

1. I have records with the field name_entry like **udhaya, udaya, udhaya kumar, uthaya**. But all the four are the same person and the actual spell is udhaya kumar.
2. In this scenario **i need to find the person record and update duplicates into original**.
3. I have more than **20000 records** and there are **minimum 300 records** have duplicates like it.
   i need solution for this scenario.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: If the names are different, how is the database supposed to know they're the same person? What other information is available that could show that these records are in fact the same person?

Comment: The title says Mysql, the tag says Oracle; which one?

Answer (score 1):

At Database level, There is no way to determine a similar spelled(mis-spelled) word.

However, There are Few natural language processing libraries - Stanford NLP([Stanford_NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/)), Apache Open NLP([Open NLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)) etc - Name Entity Recognition can be extended, training custom models. From which, you can group the similar spelled word and remove duplicates. This is complex, plus the accuracy of results depends on how well the models are trained.

However, From your question, this is a only way to achieve.